# IFileOperation::DeleteItem doesn't work in system directory .Local

Tags: c, file, com, directory

I trying to delete not empty folder `sysprep.exe.Local` from `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep`.
First, I try remove only root `test` directory:

```
...
res = SHCreateItemFromParsingName("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sysprep\\sysprep.exe.Local", NULL, IID_ShellItem, &isrc);
if (res != 0) printf("Error: %#X\n", res);
res = fileOp.lpVtbl.DeleteItem(fileOp, isrc, NULL);
if (res != 0) printf("Error: %#X\n", res);
res = fileOp.lpVtbl.PerformOperations(fileOp);
if (res != 0) printf("Error: %#X\n", res);
...
```

Later, I try remove all files in `test` folder, then remove `sysprep.exe.Local` folder itself.

Every time, I run my programm - I have `res == 0`. No errors, but files and folder are in the same place. When I try to remove not empty `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\test` directory - it was successfully disappeared.

Firstly, I think, files and folders will be removed after reboot - nope.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

`System32`, as the name indicates, is a system directory which holds critical files. It's protected against inadvertent file removal. Do not create files there, either.

Exceptions to this rule might be found in MSDN for special cases, but then the specific functions to use will be clear from context. E.g. driver installation will create files there, but you still don't call `CreateFile` to do so.

## [edit]

Now that you've identified that you're not just trying to remove files from System32, but actual parts of the Operating System, this confirms the suspicion.

If you rightclick on `SysPrep.EXE`, you will see it's owned by `TrustedInstaller`. This identifies it as a protected file which is managed by Windows Update. Not only will you fail to delete it, your attempts will probably set off every decent anti-virus program.

Comment: Change question text. I tried to remove sysprep.exe.Local directory, but can't

Comment: There's still some remnants of `test` which you changed to `sysprep`, though.

Comment: No, it's me, who create sysprep.exe.Local. And I do it from same application< from which I want to delete it after all. And I can't. Ithink, my question is bad described, but I can't delete it from SO, and I can't mark your answer as correct, coz it's didn't solve my problem :-(
Sorry about that.